# Angular: How do I get data from an event inside a service to my component?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, websocket, socket.io

I am currently writing an angular project that opens a websocket connection with a NodeJS server. This is the service:

```
export class WebsocketService {

  socket : any;

  constructor() { }

  setupSocketConnection(){
    this.socket = io(environment.SOCKET_ENDPOINT);
    this.socket.emit('message', 'The client wants to intruduce itself to the server');

    this.socket.on('broadcast', (data: string) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

  disconnect() {
    if (this.socket) {
      this.socket.disconnect();
    }
  }
}
```

and this is my component:

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = '-'; 

  constructor(private websocket : WebsocketService) { }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.websocket.setupSocketConnection();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.websocket.disconnect();
  }
}
```

My question is: how can I pass "data" from the broadcast event listener into the component to display it there? Another service would be a solution, but I dont think it would be a good one. I could also put the listener into a function and call it from the component, but wouldn't that violate the encapsulation concepts of services?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use BehaviorSubject by following theses steps:

Imagine sending JSON object holding a "type" field: Make sure to stringify data sent using

1- Server side:

```
JSON.stringify({type: "message", value: "whatever"})
```

2- Now client side

```
export class WebsocketService {

  // Put the right data type here
  message = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  connection = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');

  socket : any;

  constructor() { }

  setupSocketConnection(){
    this.socket = io(environment.SOCKET_ENDPOINT);
    this.socket.emit('message', 'The client wants to intruduce itself to the server');

    this.socket.on('broadcast', (data: string) => {
      const jsonObject = JSON.parse(data);
      switch (jsonObject.type) {
        case "message":
          this.message.next(jsonObject.value);
          break;

        case "connection":
          this.connection.next(jsonObject.value);
          break;

        default:
          throw new Error('Unknown message type' + jsonObject.type)
          break;
      }
    });
  }

  disconnect() {
    if (this.socket) {
      this.socket.disconnect();
    }
  }
}
```

And on there other hand, just subscribe to your data behaviorSubject emited values.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  title = '-'; 

  subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];
  constructor(private websocket : WebsocketService) { }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.websocket.setupSocketConnection();
    this.websocket.message.subscribe(value => {
        // Do your stuff here.
        console.log(value);
    })

    this.websocket.connection.subscribe(value => {
        // Do your stuff here.
        console.log(value);
    })
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.websocket.disconnect();
    this.subscriptions.forEach(s => s.unsubscribe());
    this.subscription = [];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was really stuck here, I couldnt find any resources regarding this problem.
I will implement this now. Sadly I cannot upvote you sicne I have zero reputation, otherwhise I would

Comment: No problem, i'm here to help, not grasp points ;).

Comment: Hey, I have a follow up question. I have decided to use a single websocket that handles the login and everything else. Now i am wondering how i could change the BehaviorSubject to only give the component the data it needs instead of everything?

Comment: Why don't you send JSON through server, then parse it in front. Make sure to add a "type" field, then based on "type" value, use a different BehaviorSubject and subscribe to it to fulfill your goal ?